# Change Active Directory User password using iOS

Tags: ios, active-directory, ldap

I have to create an iOS app that allows the user to verify the password expiration date and to change the active directory password.

I found some iOS libraries:

Microsoft iOS Active Directory SDK - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc
iOSPorts - https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts

I checked the source code of the first library and it doesn't seem to provide the change password feature so I though I could go for the iOSPorts library that uses OpenLDAP.

Do you know if there is any compatibility problem between OpenLDAP and Active Directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at Windows Server Active Directory, or Azure Active Directory?
If the latter: Azure AD does not support LDAP, it uses the Graph API instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, It's a Windows Server Active Directory, can I use iOSPorts with openLDAP for everything?

Comment: I notified the Windows Server AD guys to take a look at your Q, hopefully they'll get back to you soon on this